# Literature on Bayesian stuff with Normal Distribution?

Tags: distributions, bayesian, normal-distribution, references, conjugate-prior

I am writing something on Bayesian Analysis involving the normal distribution. I know that the conjugate prior is the so-called normalized Gamma inverse distribution, I know the update rule for the hyperparameters and I know that the predictive distribution is the student's t-distribution. The only place I was able to find where these facts are at least stated is [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior).

I have carried out the computation by myself as well and they are quite lengthy (I do not want to include them in the document I am writing).

Question: Does somebody know a reliable source (like a book about statistics / probability theory) where I could refer to for the proofs of these facts?

Wikipedia only mentions Murphy, Kevin P. (2007). "Conjugate Bayesian analysis of the Gaussian distribution" ([pdf](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf)) but this seems unfinished and rather "unofficial"...

Comment: The conjugate prior for a scalar normal with unknown mean and variance is typically referred to as the "normal inverse-gamma distribution".

Comment: google 'elementary Bayesian statistics books' and you will see several. It is a matter of opinion which is 'best'. I seem to recall that the book by Peter Lee discusses the topic of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal distribution, along with binomial distribution, are the two most popular examples of distributions used for introducing Bayesian statistics. You can found them described in *any* handbook on Bayesian statistics, for example the two references mentioned by Kevin Murphy in the refereed paper

> [Bis06]  C. Bishop. *Pattern recognition and machine learning.* Springer,
>   2006
>   ...
>   [GCSR04]  A. Gelman, J. Carlin, H. Stern, and D.
>   Rubin. *Bayesian data analysis.* Chapman and Hall, 2004. 2nd edition

or other handbooks, for example the book by Kevin Murphy,

> Kevin Murphy. *Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective.* MIT
>   Press, 2012.

However the pdf document you refer to is probably the single most detailed description on this topic that you could find, so why not just quoting it? I know that quoting unpublished papers is not very popular in many academic disciplines, but come on...